# Simply check for multiple statements C#

Tags: c#, arrays, if-statement

Currently working on a small console game and was wondering if anyone has a simple way to shorten something like this:

```
if (map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "R1"
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "R2"
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "R3"
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "Z1" 
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "Z2" 
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "Z3"
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "S1 " 
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "S2" 
 || map[playerX - 1, playerY] == "S3")
```

making a list or something and checking if `map[playerX-1, playerY]` is equal to any of the objects in it or something.

Thanks for the help in advance.
Lukas Leder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The particular matching values you are interested in (`R1`, `Z1` etc) should be populated into a `HashSet`.

```
HashSet hashSet = new HashSet<string>
{
    "R1",
    "R2",
    "R3",
    "Z1",
    "Z2",
    "Z3",
    "S1 ", // I am unclear whether you want this space or not
    "S2",
    "S3"
};
```

Then use:

```
if (hashSet.Contains(map[playerX - 1, playerY])
```

*`HashSet` has a consistently fast [`Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440(v=vs.110).aspx) function (shown above) which will suit your purposes. As @FilipCordas mentions below, you should consider declaring this `HashSet` as a `static readonly` field to ensure you only need to initialise it once.*

Comment: i have never worked with a hashset before and was wondering if you could tell me how to create one.

Comment: hashSet inherits from collections.Generic. You can init just like a List<> for example: HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>();

Comment: You are right that HashSet is fast for checking if element is inside the set, but for small number of elements array should be faster.

Comment: @FilipCordas Usually the difference is at like 2 or 3 items, so for all intents and purposes an array is never going to be faster, that is unless you have a truly horrible hash code for the type in question.

Comment: @Servy Yes and no. I run the test for the array in question on 1000000 iterations the difference was about 40ms with HashSet being faster. But that is given you are not creating a new HashSet on every method call like in the answer. So he should make his HashSet a static readonly variable and there will be some performance boost with HashSet.

Answer (score 2):

Jep, as @mjwills pointed out.

In fact, all `IList` or `IDictionary` descendants and similar have a `Contains` method. So its your choice which type of list or set fits best your needs.

A list for example is instanciated `List<string> a = new List<string>(); a.Add("b");`

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` also supports `Contains` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb352880%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 . But I'd _usually_ recommend `HashSet` since it has a more consistent performance profile.

Comment: Ahh :-D in my haste I looked up `IEnumerable` which doesnt supports it and overlooked `IEnumerable<T>`. Ok, good to know that performance point